# Difference between Component{} vs Component<Props>{} in react/react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have setup the `react native` environment. When first time i opened the `App.js` i found:

```
class MyApp extends Component<Props>{
    ...
}
```

and normally we do:

```
class MyApp extends Component{
    ...
}
```

Please can anyone tell what is `<Props>` and why we use `<Props>` in `react/react native`? A single example will be more appreciated.

Comment: The `<Props>` part tells the compiler / Code Editor what type of variable is passed to the constructor when the Component is created. It is not needed at all and can be removed, but serves its purposes on rather large code bases when you're not sure what type of variable is needed.

Comment: In a word, **type safety**. Or two I guess.

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are viewing is actually using Flow types. Flow is a static type checker for JavaScript developed by Facebook.

Reference: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Comment: As i read the documentation basics, does this flow module is already installed in react native?

Comment: @DhuBytes it depends on how you setup your react-native environment. e.g. using create-react-native-app or manually? you can check whether `babel-plugin-react-flow-props-to-prop-types` directory exists in `node_modules` directory or not

Comment: No, if the **<Props>** instruction is exist in the **App.js** then it simply means that the **flow** module is installed as well, right?

Comment: I am doing the native development, so, i found the **<Props>**.

Comment: it should be installed probably. Please update your question to add "how you setup your project?" You can quickly build and run your project to check if its working? it won't build if flow is not configured with babel

Comment: What is **babel** used for in the terms of **flow** and **react native**?

Comment: Babel is JavaScript transpiler. Babel flow plugin will be used to convert JavaScript with flow into non-flow code at build time.